# iOS AlertView App Extension

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, uialertcontroller, custom-keyboard

I'm working in a custom `keyboard` `(iOS App Extension)`. I have a `UICollectionView` in my `Keyboard` `Layout`, so when one `item` is selected I want to show a `message` (`UIAlerView` for example).

Here is my code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 ...

UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                              message:@"Enter User Credentials"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I get this error: `'Feature not available in extensions of type com.apple.keyboard-service'`

So...is there any way to show a `message` from an `App Extension`?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example. The `IKEA Emoticons Keyboard` shows a message (like an `Android Toast` after selecting one item).

I also have tried this library:

[iOS Toast Library](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. It's not the best solution, but at least I get the effect that I wanted.

I've created a `View` simulating a `Toast` in the `xib` file and set it to `hidden`.

When the item is selected, I show the "faked" `Toast` for 2 seconds and hide it again.

```
self.popUpView.hidden = NO;

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.popUpView.hidden = YES;
});
```

I don't know if it's a good solution, but I really had to find a solution for that.

For Swift you can use this :

```
self.popUpView.isHidden = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        self.popUpView.isHidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Sad to say that, but there's no way to show a UIAlertView in keyboard extension. Actually, nothing above the frame of InputViewController can be showed. It's pretty clear in the Apple's doc:

> ...a custom keyboard can draw only within the primary view of its UIInputViewController object... it is not possible to display key artwork above the top edge of a custom keyboard’s primary view, as the system keyboard does on iPhone when you tap and hold a key in the top row.

As for message inside the keyboard, there are some useful libraries that can help us with it. For example https://github.com/scalessec/Toast and https://github.com/sergeylenkov/PTHintController.

Comment: Yeah I've read the Apple's doc of course, but there should be a way to do it because I've seen that functionality in some apps like that one for example https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ikea-emoticons/id958943883?mt=8

Comment: @Ale Well, that's new. Can you put a screenshot or something?

Comment: Now I see. It's just message inside the keyboard. I'm thinking https://github.com/scalessec/Toast is what you need.

Comment: no, it doesn't work...I get this error `unrecognized selector sent to instance ...'`

Comment: yes...but still not working  :/ the error is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView makeToast:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d4d230'`

Comment: Well, did you use the `UIView+Toast.h` header file?

Comment: Anyway, the point is, it has nothing to do with keyboard extension anymore. Just how to use this Toast library.

Comment: Yes I'm using `#import "UIView+Toast.h"`. Well, good to know that the problem is not the ` keyboard extension`, at least i know it's possible :) I keep trying thank you very much