# Alert on an App in iOS8 from extension keyboard

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

Need some help with this - How do I pop an alert on an App in iOS 8 from extension keyboard ?  Please suggest solutions either in Swift or in Objective C.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS AlertView App Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825154/ios-alertview-app-extension)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. It is not a duplicate though, as I am looking for an alert that users can actually act on.  The solution provided there is more of a workaround (as mentioned by Ale) by creating a fake view that hides for 2 seconds.  Any other ideas?  Thanks much in advance.

Comment: You have to take a similar approach. You cannot draw outside the keyboard from a keyboard extension.